# Tempate not displayed on the page attribute section while adding or editing the pages

Tags: iis, wordpress, templates, themes

I have used wordpress and there is a section page attributes which includes Parent, Template and order. What my problem is i am not being able to see the templates to select while adding the pages. One problem is that the current theme is not displayed and it shows nothing on Current theme. I have two themes and both listed as not used themes.

The server i have used is IIS server. Is there anyway i can solve this issue? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this wasn't clear, but with the *Template* select box on the *Edit Page* screen, you select one *template* in your current *theme*, you can't just switch to another *theme* here. This is explained in [the documentation on creating new Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages_Add_New_SubPanel#Page_Templates), which also has information and examples on creating new templates.

If you have a problem with your theme, try re-activating it by selecting another theme and then your theme again. Make sure to [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) to see error messages that might otherwise be hidden.